# Bootstrap dropdown-toggle no longer working after implementing javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a navbar that has some dropdowns and it was all going good. However, I decided I needed some js for other functions. So I pasted this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is the code for the dropdown:

```
<div class="bottomHeader collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
<ul class ="navbar-nav" style = "position:relative; left: 560px;">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Resources for </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu boxes" style="left: 110px; text-align: left">
      <a style="padding-left: 10px;" href="#">Students</a><br>
      <a style="padding-left: 10px;" href="#">Faculty and staff</a><br>
      <a style="padding-left: 10px;" href="#">Alumni</a><br>
      <a style="padding-left: 10px;" href="#">Parents</a><br>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

For some reason the dropdown just stopped working. If I remove the bootstrap script it works again. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Where's the `ul` for your `li`'s?

Comment: my bad I forgot to include it in the code snippet, I do have in my code tho. After the <div> and before the <li>

Comment: Could you elaborate "stopped working"? If I take your code, add it to the navbar wrapper as illustrated in the documentation, this seems to work fine?

Comment: Before I put the three script tags, the code was working normally. If I clicked on "Resources for", the dropdown would appear. However once I pasted the three tags, the dropdown no longer appeared.